# MySQL 5.7 set empty root password permanently

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7 by default does not allow to login as root with empty password. We can do some simple steps to disable password for root (it is well known now):

```
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = '';
flush privileges;
```

But after some time (a month or two) mysql reset this options and root login require password again. How to make these changes of disabled root pass permanent?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Because on Earth I use locally installed mysql for developing that absolutely do not need any password.

Comment: Its a perfectly good reason for a developer who has a secure environment.